# Debugger with Eclipse on a macOS Catalina

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, eclipse-cdt

I've macOS Catalina and Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developer, Version: 2021-03 (4.19.0) and I need to use EclipseCDT debugger. Following the steps  at [macOS 10.15 Catalina gdb problem for C++ Debugging in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59393100/macos-10-15-catalina-gdb-problem-for-c-debugging-in-eclipse) I still have problems. Namely, the Debug window doesn't show up.

The only difference between my steps and the ones from the tutorial is the gdb version: mine is 10.1, while the other is 8.3.

I've found this FAQ link: https://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ, where seems to be possible to use LLDB debugger, but I can't find the detailed instructions. Any approach is fine to me, I just need a working debugger

Comment: https://www.thomasvitale.com/how-to-setup-gdb-and-eclipse-to-debug-c-files-on-macos-sierra/ have you tried this?

Comment: Yes, multiple times actually. As I wrote in my post, I believe the problem is that his gdb version is 8.3, while mine is 10.1 @YunhaoLin Do u know if it's possible to install a previous gdb version with home-brew? If not, I'd like to use LLDB too, but I can't find any way to do this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65867339/im-currently-experiencing-an-error-with-gdb-debugging-on-eclipse-macos-big-sur try this